# Why can't my web application application context load my jar properties file?

Tags: spring-mvc, classloader, spring-boot

Here is my setup / context.  I have a JAR project that is using spring-boot 1.1.4 which uses Java configuration to load a properties file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(name="appProps", value="classpath*:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
public class DataJpaApplication {


@Autowired Environment env;


@Bean
//note, this PSPSHC is ours derived from the Spring one with specialized code.
public static org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer encryptionPropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer();
    encryptionPropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer
            .setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return encryptionPropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer;
}
}
```

This jar works fine with unit tests standalone.   I then try to incorporate it into a web app (spring mvc web app not using spring-boot) making it a maven dependency and adding it to the context like this:

```
<beans:bean id="jpaConfigBean"
    class="com.somepackage.DataJpaApplication" />
```

I have a web app unit test that attempt to load the web app's application context and that works fine (including loading the context and property file from the jar).  However, when I deploy this web app to a container (tcServer), it fails with the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application-local.properties]
```

**edit**

A clarification about the error above.  The web app is loading its context and importing the jar file's context.  It is this jar project that is loading the application-local.properties via @PropertySource.  So, could this be around parent/child context interactions?

NOTE: No where does the code prepend a slash.

Here is how I am bootstrapping the spring config in the web app:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:**/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I have checked the following types of things:

1. Confirmed the maven generated manifest has a classpath entry for the jar file in the war file.
2. Changing the web.xml to use /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml (standard path) instead
3. Deploy this web app in JBoss instead of tc
4. move the application-*.property file to another folder and refer to that folder
5. copy the *.property file to the web app project
6. confirmed the WTP deployment assembly in fact references maven
7. opened up the generated war file and confirmed the jar file has the file in the expected location.

and several other things with no success.

I don't see the issue.  Please help figure out where the bug/misconfiguration is.   Also, let me know if there is further configuration or files you need to see to help debug this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Scott

***edit***

complete web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>log4j.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
 <!-- commented out for debugging...trying to reduce the complexity to get to root cause
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:**/*Context.xml,     
        classpath*:**/*-context.xml
     </param-value>
  </context-param> -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath*:**/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
</listener>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>
</error-page> 
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
 <location>/WEB-INF/views/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>  
</web-app>
```

complete (obfuscated) servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="jpaConfigBean"
        class="com.somepackage.DataJpaApplication" />


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.somepackage.*" />

    <!-- Needed for transaction methods in controllers -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <beans:bean id="ehCacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:shared="true" />

    <beans:bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cacheManager-ref="ehCacheManager" />

    <cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="0 0 3 * * *" />
        <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
            initial-delay="0" fixed-rate="#{ T(java.lang.Long).MAX_VALUE }" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>


    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <beans:bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="favorParameter" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:value>
                html=text/html
                json=application/json
                xml=application/xml
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Not sure there is anything relevant in these files besides what I highlighted above, but added per request and for clarity.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to link related entries but I did review the following other similar questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035464/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318533/why-cant-my-regular-application-context-load-my-properties-file

Comment: At a glance it looks correct, but there's a lot that we don't see.  Can you post your full web.xml and servlet-context.xml?

Comment: For starters you get 2 instances of your configration. One you declared manually and another is detected using `component-scan` (for which you should remove `.*` from the base-package name, it is name not a pattern, also you can remove the `<context:annotation-config />` as that is already implied). Also I'm not sure where you aer using Spring boot because you are doing a whole lot to work around the magic and easy Spring Boot gives you.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the reply.  We made the changes in the app and it made it "worse" in that it could not find beans it used to find.  The .* is a doh! and obvious.  As far as spring boot usage, it is complicated.  The project that is using spring-boot is not mentioned here and is NOT using ANY XML configuration.  It was written separately from the web-app project which that developer did not know or use spring-boot.  So in short, by necessity, not choice, we have a mixture of both being combined into a WAR deploy.  Any further suggestions?